# Permission/Multiple access to Alfresco Explorer?/Share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm newbie to Alfresco.

I've been installed it for a week and have been trying to use it. But I still confusing with it too. - -"
I've some questions for Alfresco.
- Is the Alfresco provide many user from many computer access to Alfresco Explorer at the same time? (I can access it from my pc but cannot access to Alfresco Explorer/Share from my co-worker pc)

- Is the Alfresco need to configure for host permission that can access to it? (I'm log out and close my browser then try to use my co-worker pc to access it but it cannot access to Alfresco Explorer/Share.)

when request from my co-worker pc, I founded this :

ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved
..
..
Connection to failed.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to configure anything explicitly for that. Only thing normally require is mapping machine ip with hostname but that is not mendatory. 
Once you install alfresco on one machine and that machine is connected with other machines through intranet then you should be easily able to access that through the machine IP on which it is installed.

```
http://<machineIP>:<port>/alfresco
http://<machineIP>:<port>/share
```

Check weather you are able to ping your machine ip address from your coworekers machine or not if that works then you should be able to access it. through above urls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I check in my co-worker pc it is not getting. we are using same router and i checked the firewall also there was no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt at machine from which you want to reach Alfresco app on your local machine and type in

```
telnet <your_local_machine_IP> <app_server_port>
```

for example

```
telnet mitpatoliyaPC 8080
```

Until you are able to see black screen with blinker in upper left corner you don't need to think of Alfresco or any problems related to it.